# 2D Water Shader

Tags: unity, shaders, water

I am trying to build a 2D Water shader and I am using Unity but the plateform isn't a problem.
Here is an example of what I am trying to reproduce :
[Limbo water shader](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phChFfi4GOs)
Are there any good tutorial or whitepaper about creating such effect blur and displacement ? I am not talking about waves or something but only the depth of the water.
Is it a Camera shader or an object shader ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except the spluttering / water jets (seems to be done with particles) it looks like a displacement shader.

Check out this http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter19.html

It is in 3D but the theory behind it should provide helpful if it is that kind of water effect you look for.

Comment: Thanks for the link ! Yes of course, I am not talking about the spluttering / water jets.

Answer (score 0):

I have Unity Pro. I saw that the best way to achieve such effect is to use Grabpass in the shader. But there are two problems with this system :

- It seems that Grabpass is quite heavy for mobile as said here [Using Grabpass & IOS/Android devices](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/129364-Using-Grabpass-amp-IOS-Android-devices) . But as I am learning shader, I don't know any other system to create refraction.
- There is an issue with foreground objects, they are refracted too. There is a solution here [GPU Gems - Refractions](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter19.html) posted by Valmond.

Another interesting link : [Unite 11 - Shadowgun](http://video.unity3d.com/video/3709506/unite-11-shadowgun-rendering) The fluid part is at about 30:00.